# filter_var for password

Tags: php, filter, passwords

Good evening.

I recently bump into the filter_var() of PHP. I am wondering if what type of sanitize filter and filter flag should I use with **filter_var()** for sanitizing my password variable? Or is there a better way to sanitize it?

Comment: There is no need to sanitize password. 
More complex and uncleaner passwords, more secure they are.

Comment: What sanitation are you talking about?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no need for sanitizing your password as you need to hash it anyway.

Comment: Note to those who don't hash: go hash your passwords.

Comment: Note to those who hash their passwords: don't forget to add a random salt

Comment: Note to those who hash their passwords and use a random salt: use strong hashing but don't forget other security aspects, or salt+hashing is useless

Comment: @Damien - Can you detail more on "other security aspects"?

Comment: Force strong passwords and prevent brute force attacks for example.

Comment: @Dee brute force attacks on your login, SQL injections, XSS, CSRF, and as matino said,you should enforce a strong password policy especially on higher-role users, or your admin whose password is "qwerty" will destroy all your nuke-proof website

Comment: In general this is correct, but there are times when you can't hash the password first.  One example is if you are using an LDAP / Active Directory server to authenticate users.  Then the password must be used in your script in order to pass it along.

Comment: Even though there should be no need to sanitize the password, you should simply pass what user typed to the LDAP authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

```
there is lot way to validate password
```

but of caurse you can do it with filter_var() function
there is the code`regex is array contains all my regex pattern`

```
$option = array(
'options' => array('regexp' => self::REGEX['address'])
);
return filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, $option) == $val;
```